# Why my upgrade to Windows 10 restarted?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I'm upgrading my Windows 7 computer to Windows 10 using Windows Update. Then when I reach 99%, it resets to 0%. I spent long time waiting for it to succeed in our slow internet connection then restarted. What is the cause of this and how to fix this?

Comment: I suggest you download the Windows 10 1511 .ISO and upgrade using that method.

Comment: Oh thanks, but Windows 10 download takes month in our WiFi to download. Will the ISO resume after I shut my computer down?